# AddThis email button

Tags: javascript, html, addthis

Using the AddThis plugin (http://www.addthis.com/) I am using the code below to put an email button on my website. But despite setting the target="_blank" it still opens a new tab rather than window. So I am wondering if there is a way to make it open up in a new browser window and not a tab.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://api.addthis.com/oexchange/0.8/forward/email/offer?  url=${siteURL}/${ourURL}&title=${addThisEmailTitle}" rel="nofollow"><img border="none" src="http://cache.addthiscdn.com/icons/v1/thumbs/email.gif"></img></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the user and his or her browser defaults.

For example in Chrome `target="_blank"` opens in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

The target attribute doesn't help you. AddThis uses a modal pop-up to open the e-mail and other share services (eg. Pinterest). You can use the [Addthis Sharing Endpoints](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381265-addthis-sharing-endpoints) that doesn't uses their script and make it work how you want.